# SQL Querying - Matching datetimes vs Matching integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a bunch of data in my database and I want to filter out data that has been stored that for longer than a week. I'm using SQLServer and I found that I could use the '`DATEDIFF`' function.

At the moment it works great and fast but I don't have a lot of records at the moment therefore anything runs quite smoothly.

After some research online I found out that the comparison of integers in databases is faster than the comparison of strings, I assume at this point that the comparison of datetimes (using the given function) is even slower at a major scale.

Let's say my database table content looks like this:
[image]

Currently I would filter out records that are older like a week like so:

```
SELECT * FROM onlineMainTable WHERE DATEDIFF(wk, Date, GETDATE()) > 1
```

I assume that this query would be quite slow if there were a thousand rows tin the table.

The status column represents a calculation status, I wondered if I would speed up the process if I were to look for a specific status instead of matching datetimes, for me in order to set that status to the one that represents 'old records' I need to update those rows before I select them, it would look something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET Status = -1 WHERE NOT Status = -1 AND DATEDIFF(wk, Date, GETDATE()) > 1;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Status = -1;
```

I used the '-1' as an example.

So obviously I could be wrong but I **think** updating in this case would be fast enough since there won't be that many records to update since older ones have already been updated with its status. The selection would be faster aswell since I would be matching integers instead of datetimes.

The downside to my (possible) solution is that I would query twice every time I fetch data, even when it might not be needed (if every row is newer than 1 week).

It comes down to this: Should I compare datetimes or should I update an integer column based on that datetime and then select using the comparison of those ints?

If there is a different/better way of doing this i'm all ears.

**Context**
I am making a webapp for quotation requests. Requests should expire after a week since they won't be valid at that point. I need to both display valid requests and expired requests (so costumers have an overview). All these requests are stored in a database table.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean by "longer than a week"?  You code is different from keeping data from the past 7 days.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query written above fetches the rows that are older than a week, all data is kept

Comment: . . Your logic keeps all rows from the most recent complete week and any days since then.  It is unclear if that is what you mean by "that has been stored that for longer than a week".  That is not how I would interpret your description.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are the objects that are design to improve select queries performances the drawback is that they slow down insert delete and update operations, so they have to be used when necessary. Generally DBMS provide tools to explain queries execution plan.

Maybe you just need to add an index on Date column:

```
create index "index_name" on onlineMainTable(Date)
```

and  query could be

```
 SELECT * FROM onlineMainTable WHERE Date > DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE());
```

Comment: Why would indexing speed this up? Maybe a stupid question but wouldn't it have to loop through the entire table whether it is indexed or not?

Comment: if there is an index it will be scan instead and if it's implemented as a binary tree it's already sorted

Comment: I am not familiar with indexing, but I assume you mean a clustered index?

Comment: No i'm talking about not-clustered index, it's a structure which only contains the values and points to the rows of the table, whereas SQLServer clustered index contain the row so table can have only one clustered index.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, thanks for the fix, I couldn't check the syntax and I had to confuse with drop index syntax table_name.index_name.

Comment: Even without the index, filtering on a field, as in this answer, is usually faster than filtering on a function result.